# Getting Duplicates on To Do List, yet local storage unaffected

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm new to javascript and I am trying to use local storage to save user input. With the code as it is right now, I get the user input saved to local storage, but the list does not save when refreshing the page. Also, the user input appends to the to do list multiple times. Thanks for taking a look.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const form = document.querySelector('#new-task-form');
    const input = document.querySelector('#new-task-input');
    const listElement = document.querySelector('#tasks');

    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || [];

    console.log(todos)

    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const task = input.value;
        
        if(!task) {
            alert('You definitely have something to do...')
            return
        }

        const todo = {
            content: task,
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)
        }

        todos.push(todo);
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));

        todos.forEach(todo => {
        const taskElement = document.createElement('div');
        taskElement.classList.add('task');

        const taskContentElement = document.createElement('div');
        taskContentElement.classList.add("content");

        taskElement.appendChild(taskContentElement);

        const taskInputElement = document.createElement("input")
        taskInputElement.classList.add("text");
        taskInputElement.type = "text";
        taskInputElement.value = task;
        taskInputElement.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');

        taskContentElement.appendChild(taskInputElement);

        const taskActionsElement = document.createElement('div');
        taskActionsElement.classList.add("actions");

        const taskEditElement = document.createElement('button');
        taskEditElement.classList.add('edit');
        taskEditElement.innerHTML = "Edit";

        const taskDeleteElement = document.createElement('button');
        taskDeleteElement.classList.add('delete');
        taskDeleteElement.innerHTML = "Delete";

        taskActionsElement.appendChild(taskEditElement);
        taskActionsElement.appendChild(taskDeleteElement);

        taskElement.appendChild(taskActionsElement);

        listElement.appendChild(taskElement);

        input.value = '';

        taskEditElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (taskEditElement.innerText.toLowerCase() == 'edit') {
                taskInputElement.removeAttribute('readonly');
                taskInputElement.focus();
                taskEditElement.innerText = "Save";
                localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
        
            } else {
                taskInputElement.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
                taskEditElement.innerText = 'Edit';
            }
        });

        taskDeleteElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
            todos = todos.filter(t => t != todo);
            localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
            listElement.removeChild(taskElement);
            
            });
   
        }); 

    }); 
   
});
```

The user input comes up multiple times when added to the list, depending on when added to the array. I was hoping for it to come up one time, and for it to be a normal list.

Comment: You may try taking your submit event listener out of the load event listener and clearing inside of listElement like this 'listElement.innerHTML = ";' before submitting the form. You may also divide your code into functions to make it cleaner.

Comment: @MithatErcan I tried that and nothing populated to the page. Thank you for looking into a possible solution